# Can kitchen salt break a LED lamp circuits/board? (weird problem)

Tags: led, light

Hello everyone I have a really weird situation.

I had two Yongnuo YN-600 Air LED photo/video lights. On these lamps it says "DC, max input 8V, 5A".

I was sold AC adapters to those lamps 12V 5A. They were working properly in the beginning. Then I started traveling with those and at one point lots of normal kitchen salt spilled in my travel bag (I didn't notice). Some of this salt got into the boards of the lamps - I thought it does not matter so I used the lamps normally.

Suddenly one time one lamp after turning on with the AC adapter started blinking and then something got burned on the board - lamp completely dead. The 2nd lamp worked well.

Then 2 weeks later the same started happening to the 2nd lamp (it still had some salt inside the case). Now it blinks every time I turn it on but I immediately switch it off because I'm afraid of breaking it completely.
So now I am not sure - is all of this a salt fault? Or maybe one of my AC adapters is faulty and broke both lights? Any suggestions about how can I check which AC adapter may be faulty? I want to buy new lights but if one of them is bad then I don't want to destroy new lights...

If anyone can comment or help me with this I would be really grateful!

Comment: Salt easily absorbs moisture and wet salt conducts electricity.

Comment: salt is corrosive .... salt on roads rusts out cars ... sea water rusts out ships like crazy .... you must be a very young person if you think that salt is inert

Comment: You're powering them with 12V when they say `max input 8V`?

Comment: Holy shit thank you guys for replies. I'm 30yrs old but ignorant in many ways lol. Also @Jashaszun they said 12V AC is good for these lamps even though on the case it says max 8V... can this be true? The lamps worked well before the "salt" incident... if the 12V was to much would it destroy the lamps immediately or just degrade them faster over time?

Comment: Easy on the profanity lol.

Comment: You were killing those lamps with 12V and salt sealed their fate. You might still salvage second one if you open and clean it thoroughly and switch to 7.2~7.4V, 5~6A adapter immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Specs:  YN600 Air adopts **double mains** input,which supports batteries of NP-F Series external DC main of 8V and 5A.
YN600 Air adopts YONGNUO proprietary LED constant current driving technology
There is also a 12V 5A supply.

————

You are seeing failures with the line voltage AC to DC converter not the 8V constant current.

The salt must be completely removed with a good quality isopropyl alcohol with several rinses and then forced air dried for many hours to ensure no moisture under chips.

The LEDs are still good and you can run from 12V.

They use salt to boil water rapidly with just electrodes at line voltage and will fry the converter if used again and not carefully cleaned of all salt ions which will not be easy and may consume a bottle or two and require vacuuming.

Salt is corrosive and it may be easy to destroy it. So look for YouTube videos and chalk this up to experience.

Comment: Thank you Tony for answering this is an amazing explanation. I'm going to follow your isopropyl alcohol method to rinse the second lamp and try to recover it. Thank you! 

Also because I see you are really knowledgable and I'm still ignorant in the electronic stuff, if my power adapter for these lamps is marked "AC", and not "AC-DC" it is still good for them? Thank you!

Comment: Also use deionized water after to rinse isoprop contaminants and thorough vacuum and warm air forced dry for many hours

Comment: Amazing tips thank you, I hope I'll be able to recover it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the manufacturer has approved 12V supply for these. They definitely should change the product markings to dual 8V @5A max / 12V @3.5A (or whatever) max. There are various reports of people returning 12V adapters because they (quite reasonably) expected to receive 8V ones to conform to the markings.

Probably the salt + moisture from the air did it. Your profile does not show your location, but here in the northern hemisphere the summer has arrived and with it significantly increased humidity in many places. Or maybe they got some rain. It's possible if you clean the boards carefully as @Tony suggests you may be able to recover functionality, especially if it hasn't quit entirely. If they have quit, it's possible that a trace or traces have been eaten through and they can be repaired. Sad.

Comment: Thanks you Spehro for a comment and advice! It is awesome that you too the effort to check the specs for these lamps and shed some light that it can be used with 12V. 

I traveled by plane with them and kept them in my hand luggage through Asia and to Europe after and it is real humid now in Asia as a rainy season... so what you are saying seems correct. Thank you!